# Iterating through XML using XPathNavigator and XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm working on a project where I accept an XML file and have a need to iterate through the XML and output the text values of specific nodes and I'm struggling with the best approach to doing this.

I'm using the following code which works for the single XPath node I've defined which works fine, but I need to extract additional nodes and their associated text. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I've been reading through the `XPathNavigator`, `XPathNodeIterator`, `XMLReader` documentation from Microsoft and using their examples, but none seem to fit this specific use case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.XPath;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("Security_Policy.xml");
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("//Rule_Number");
            while (nodes.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nodes.Current.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant block of XML I'm working with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <rule>
        <Name></Name>
        <Class_Name>security_rule</Class_Name>
        <Rule_UUID>{9BA1463A-00D0-4819-88B6-650407733A96}</Rule_UUID>
        <Rule_Number>1</Rule_Number>
        <action>
          <action>
            <Name>accept</Name>
            <Class_Name>accept_action</Class_Name>
            <action><![CDATA[]]></action>
            <identity_settings>
              <Name></Name>
              <Class_Name>identity_action_settings</Class_Name>
              <allow_ad_query>true</allow_ad_query>
              <allow_captive_portal>true</allow_captive_portal>
              <allow_identity_agent>true</allow_identity_agent>
              <allowed_sources><![CDATA[All Sources]]></allowed_sources>
              <redirect_to_captive_portal>false</redirect_to_captive_portal>
              <require_packet_tagging>false</require_packet_tagging>
              <type><![CDATA[identity_action_settings]]></type>
            </identity_settings>
            <macro><![CDATA[RECORD_CONN]]></macro>
            <type><![CDATA[accept]]></type>
          </action>
        </action>
        <comments><![CDATA[]]></comments>
        <disabled>false</disabled>
        <dst>
          <Name></Name>
          <Class_Name>rule_destination</Class_Name>
          <members>
            <reference>
              <Name></Name>
              <Table>network_objects</Table>
            </reference>
            <reference>
              <Name></Name>
              <Table>network_objects</Table>
            </reference>
          </members>
          <compound></compound>
          <op><![CDATA[]]></op>
        </dst>
        <global_location><![CDATA[middle]]></global_location>
        <install>
          <Name></Name>
          <Class_Name>rule_install</Class_Name>
          <members>
            <reference>
              <Name>Any</Name>
              <Table>globals</Table>
            </reference>
          </members>
          <compound></compound>
        </install>
        <name><![CDATA[]]></name>
        <services>
          <Name></Name>
          <Class_Name>rule_services</Class_Name>
          <members>
            <reference>
              <Name>Any</Name>
              <Table>globals</Table>
            </reference>
          </members>
          <compound></compound>
          <op><![CDATA[]]></op>
        </services>
        <src>
          <Name></Name>
          <Class_Name>rule_source</Class_Name>
          <members>
            <reference>
              <Name></Name>
              <Table>network_objects</Table>
            </reference>
            <reference>
              <Name></Name>
              <Table>network_objects</Table>
            </reference>
          </members>
          <compound></compound>
          <op><![CDATA[]]></op>
        </src>
        <through>
          <Name></Name>
          <Class_Name>rule_vpn</Class_Name>
          <members>
            <reference>
              <Name>Any</Name>
              <Table>globals</Table>
            </reference>
          </members>
          <compound></compound>
        </through>
        <time>
          <time>
            <Name>Any</Name>
            <Table>globals</Table>
          </time>
        </time>
        <track>
          <track>
            <Name>Log</Name>
            <Table>tracks</Table>
          </track>
        </track>
      </rule>
```

Comment: [`Linq to XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is probably easiest to use.  Can you tell us specifically what output you want?  Your current code shows what works rather than what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your XPath path is incorrect since the "Rule_Number" element isn't the root of the document, however I'm not an XPath expert so take the below XPath suggestion with a grain of salt:

```
//rule/Rule_Number
```

Here's another way to do it since I'm a big advocate of using linq-to-xml whenever possible since it's very intuitive to use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Security_Policy.xml");
var ruleNodes = doc.Root.Elements("Rule_Number");
foreach(var node in ruleNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want elements regardless of where in the hierarchy of the XML document, you can use `doc.Descendants("TAG NAME")` to get anything with the matching "tag name" (technically the data is an `XName` in that field, but don't worry about that for now).

Comment: Was just about to suggest this.  Much easier to use this and very fast as well.

Comment: Yeah, personally I'm not a big fan of XPath.  Sure has it's place, but using newer methods of traversing XML like LINQ make life so much easier.

Comment: Thanks everyone I'm taking a look at linq to xml. I'm jumping in head first coming from perl and php so learning about the built in methods available for this type of thing has been interesting. Using that snippet above isn't returning anything, but I'm sure it's how I'm defining the doc.Root.Elements.

Comment: My snippit above assumes that <rule> is the root of your document.  You may need to add more levels to my snippit if that's not accurate.  Take a look at the getting started tutorial from MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: Yeah the root of the document isn't <rule>. I'm reading the getting started tutorial now, thanks for that. I can't unfortunately post the entire XML document as it would take quite some time to strip out some data that I can't post publically.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any questions and I can add it to my answer if it's close to your original question.

Comment: I just found the option to create a schema from the source XML in Visual Studio - Can you take a look and see what would need to be changed path wise : http://pastebin.com/Pnxewc0H

I'm trying to extract specifically 

Number
Name 
Source
Destination
VPN
Service
Action
Track
Install On
Time
Comment

Comment: Using schemas is not for reading XML files, it's for validation.  That's kind of irrelevant for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Try using xdoc.Descendents("Rule_Number"); instead of Root.Elements

Comment: Thanks guys/gals. I really do appreciate all the help.

Comment: What @jle posted will get you ALL "Rule_Number" nodes no matter what level they are within the document.

Comment: xdoc.Descendants did the trick :-) Now I just need to format the output so it's a bit more readable. Thank you all again so much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  I added that to my answer so it's complete.  Please mark it as accepted so we can close out this question.  Good luck with the rest of your coding!